# "Infinite Steps"

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, visual

[image]

Three Mathematicians standing on infinite ladder on step number 35, 192, 227 respectively.

Everyone has same two secret formula, based on current standing position(step Number) one of the formula calculates and tell individually a new and distinct step number.

All three Mathematicians have applied formula 13 times and managed to stand on the step number one

Can You Find Which Formulas They Have Used ?

Comment: I believe this  question may have more than one answer.

Comment: What is the source of this puzzle?

Comment: *Two* secret formulas? So one says what step to stand on next, and the other ... does what?

Comment: @gareth-mccaughan its based on one of the famous mathematical conjecture

Comment: You're probably looking for the Collatz formula. This is still way too broad though - any number of things can be the "applied formula".

Answer (score 4):

Obviously the answer is that

> each mathematician's formula is f(x) = 1. After applying this nine times they are all on step 1. [EDITED to add: when I wrote this, the question said 9 where it now says 13. But of course this answer works just as well with 13 as 9.]

Or, alternatively, we could close the question as too broad.

Comment: f(x)=1 for n steps will surely gives any intended answer, but distinct value at each step which is one of the condition

Comment: Distinct values at each step were not in the conditions when I wrote the answer above.

Comment: It was for the edited comment "But of course this answer works just as well with 13 as 9."

Comment: Ah, OK. Then I didn't notice all the changes that had been made when the puzzle was edited.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer but I believe there are more than one answer.

There are two formulas, so the obvious way to use these formulas is standing on an even or odd ladder number. If you are on even ladder, use first formula, otherwise use second formula below.

The formulas are;

> 1- $n/2+2$ if n is even

and

> 2- $n+1$ if n is odd

and so the final step number is

> 6

Comment: This would be one of the possible two formula for given question. can we use/tweak the same formula to take them all till step no #1

Comment: @Dharmesh you have changed to question a couple of times! (from 9 to 13, from any step no to 1...)